# HTML Cross Domain Post Method Security

Tags: html, forms, post

If I am using a purely HTML form that is using a post method to another domain, is there any data that is hitting the server (domain) to which the form is currently residing?

For example I have this form on www.example.com

```
 <form action="http://otherdomain.com" method="post">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When submit is clicked does any data actually hit the server hosting www.example.com?  This is a strange thing to explain so clean up if needed.

I am under the impression that it will not hit the server hosting www.example.com but will only post out to otherdomain.com, without passing data to www.example.com.  I believe the HTTP requests back this up.  Any information or sources would be helpful!

Comment: if that server URI accept this form parameters than yes

Comment: The current domain will not get any data only the domain you are submitting too.

Comment: epascarello if you create an answer explaining this I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say Server A accept these parameters and URI on its own server

```
http://www.serverA.com/register/firstname=john&lastname=eddy
```

When submitting the Form from Server B, to Server A with the same parameters and URL as above. Then undoubtedly Server A would accept the Server's B Request.

Any Server can behave as a Client  on any other server when it changes its role to the requester  .

A server is like any other Machine, just like your computer and this form after submission is like any other URL your are typing on your browser. when Server B talks to Server A that is called Request and when B Responds to A that is called Response. Remember HTTP is a stateless protocol which means connections are not persistent. so the machines talk with each others with requests and responses

Hope that is clear

Comment: Is server B actually sending the request or am I posting directly to server A from my browser.  Does the browser "talk" to server B at all or does it just send the data to A?